# How to make avatar stay inside in bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position my "image holder" (avatar) with bottom and top~ 3px;
But when I do that the image holder goes out of the grid.....
Here is the code:

```
<div class="container container-main">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-acc" style="padding:20px; margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="container-heading">My Account</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" class="">Account information</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">Deposit</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">Withdraw</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">My Tickets</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">transaction History</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">Perferences</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-upload">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" class="avatar">
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-up">Upload Photo</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css code for the avatar:(What should I change to make it stay inside the gird with top/bottom 3px;?)

```
.avatar{
 position: inherit;
 bottom: 3px;

 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
       -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;

      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
       -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying *bottom: 3px* (delete it) to ***avatar***, apply *padding: 3px 15px;* to parent ***col-upload*** (parent div).

```
.col-upload{
padding: 3px 15px;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/o5v0eu71/

Comment: No problem! You may mark this as the correct answer, if it fully meets your needs.